# Spinner in Fragment give error with getIndex

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have this code for my fragment, but give error in "getIndex",

```
Helper.SpinnerAdapter sa2 = new Helper.SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(),uf);
    s_estado.setAdapter(sa2);
    s_estado.setSelection(getIndex(s_estado, tae.getEstado().toString()));
```

how to procede?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method as getIndex() that's why it is giving you error

Try this:

```
s_estado.setSelection(tae.getEstado());
```

And if tae.getEstado() is a string then:

```
s_estado.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(tae.getEstado()));
```

Comment: spinner.setSelection() call the position , if i put spinner.setSelection(1) of this String array {"teste1","teste2","teste3"} will return "teste2", if i use your method give error.

Comment: Try spinner.setSelection(arrayList.indexOf(your_value));